# Making JQuery Recognise Newly Added Elements (Event Prob Solved but...)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Firstly, here's my code.

### HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="trans_type">Transaction Type</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw"></i></span>
            <select class="selectpicker form-control"  data-live-search="true"  id="trans_type" name="trans_type" required>
                <option value="" selected>Select a Transaction Type</option>
                <option value=0>Class Experiment</option>
                <option value=1>Borrowment</option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <!-- /.input-group -->
     </div>
     <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
     <div class="col-md-3" id="lyr_1">
     </div>
     <!-- /.col-md-3 #lyr_1 -->
     <div class="col-md-3" id="lyr_2">
     </div>
     <!-- /.col-md-3 #lyr_2 -->
     <div class="col-md-3" id="lyr_3">
     </div>
     <!-- /.col-md-3 #lyr_3 -->
     <div class="row"><br><br><br><br>
     </div>
     <!-- /.row -->
     <div class="col-md-3" id="lyr_4">
     </div>
     <!-- /.col-md-3 #lyr_4 -->
 </div>
 <!-- /.panel-body -->
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trans_type").change(function() {
        if($("#trans_type").val() == 0) {
            $("#lyr_1")
                .html("<img src='assets/loader1.gif' class='text-center' alt='loading...' />")
                .load('models/getborreq_fields_model.php?mode=0', {}, function() {
                $('#trans0_adv').selectpicker('refresh');
            });
            $("#lyr_2")
                .html("<img src='assets/loader1.gif' class='text-center' alt='loading...' />")
                .load('models/getborreq_fields_model.php?mode=1', {}, function(){
                $('#trans0_sub').selectpicker('refresh');
            });
            $("#lyr_3")
                .html("<img src='assets/loader1.gif' class='text-center' alt='loading...' />")
                .load('models/getborreq_fields_model.php?mode=2', {}, function(){
                $('#trans0_exp').selectpicker('refresh');
            });
            $("#lyr_4")
                .html("<img src='assets/loader1.gif' class='text-center' alt='loading...' />")
                .load('models/getborreq_fields_model.php?mode=3', {}, function(){
                $('#trans0_grp').selectpicker('refresh');
            });
        } else if ($("#trans_type").val() == 1) {
            $("#lyr_1, #lyr_2, #lyr_3, #lyr_4").empty();
        }
    });
});
```

### PHP

```
<?php
require_once '../classes/dbc_get_bor.php';
session_start();
$db_call = new dbc_get_bor();
if ($_GET["mode"] == 0) {
    echo '<label for="trans0_adv">Subject Adviser</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw"></i></span>
        <select class="selectpicker form-control"  data-live-search="true"  id="trans0_adv" name="trans0_adv" required>
            <option value="" selected>Select an Adviser</option>';
            $db_call->get_faculty();
        echo '</select>
    </div>
    <!-- /.input-group -->';
} else if ($_GET["mode"] == 1) {
    echo '<label for="trans0_sub">Subject Code</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw"></i></span>
        <select class="selectpicker form-control"  data-live-search="true"  id="trans0_sub" name="trans0_sub" required>
            <option value="" selected>Select an Adviser First</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- /.input-group -->';
} else if ($_GET["mode"] == 2) {
    echo '<label for="trans0_exp">Experiment #</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw"></i></span>
        <select class="selectpicker form-control"  data-live-search="true"  id="trans0_exp" name="trans0_exp" required>
            <option value="" selected>Select a Subject First</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- /.input-group -->';
} else if ($_GET["mode"] == 3) {
    echo '<label for="trans0_grp">Group #</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw"></i></span>
        <select class="selectpicker form-control"  data-live-search="true"  id="trans0_grp" name="trans0_grp" required>
            <option value="" selected>Select a Subject First</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- /.input-group -->';
}?>
```

### The Problem

I already fixed the Event part. I used what you guys Event Delegation by using

```
$( "#example" ).on( "click", "#example", function() {})
```

But now I'm getting problems when manipulating a newly added element
My expected "working" code here is

```
$('#lyr_1').on('change', '#trans0_adv', function () {
        $("#trans0_sub").html("<option value="" selected>Select Adviser's Subjects</option>");
    });
```

The event

```
$('#lyr_1').on('change', '#trans0_adv', function () {}
```

Can be detected but

```
$("#trans0_sub").html("<option value="" selected>Select Adviser's Subjects</option>");
```

can't. I tried to put the code inside .load() in #lyr_# divs but it doesn't work. I searched the web already but can't find an answer or anything similar to it.

Comment: Could somebody answer why I this line of code `$("#trans0_sub").html("<option value="" selected>Select Adviser's Subjects</option>");`can't be detected in my presented codes?

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically modifying a `<select>`'s selected option will not trigger the `change` event.

You will have to trigger it explicitely after performing the change using something like:

```
$("#trans0_sub").trigger('change');
```

However, people usually need to do this because of an incorrect design in the first place. I'm not saying it's always wrong to trigger events that way, but if you trigger the event **just because you want a specific known behavior to be invoked**, you would be better to **explicitely state the behavior that you want**.

E.g.

```
$('#some-select').change(function () {
    //some behavior
});

//later
$('#some-select').val(someValue).trigger('change');
```

Would be better written as:

```
$('#some-select').change(function () {
    someBehavior();
});

function someBehavior() {
}

//later

$('#some-select').val(someValue);
someBehavior();
```

Comment: The event works. I even tried using alert() to test it if it works and it did. Right now I really need to detect "a new added element from another new added element" without putting them all in one function() Edit: My event works like yours

Comment: @Calvin Could you clarify this in your question? What do you mean by **detect** a new added element? What do you expect to happen when you run the block of code you mentionned?

Comment: I'm sorry for bad explaining, that's my bad part in life and also I need to learn a lot of technical terms again. Anyway, as mostly everyone knows that jQuery function do not binds newly added dom elements. That's why there's this "Event Delegation".

Comment: What I expect to happen is when the user picks an option in select_1(trans_type) the program will make SEVERAL select/input(text) fields in the page(Currently has no problem). Then when the user picks an option in the newly added select_2(#trans0_adv), select_3(#trans0_sub) will have it's options updated using .load() based on what the value in select_2 has and this is now not happening which causes my headaches right now

Comment: *"incorrect design"* and *"Would be better written as"* are very subjective. If you work with lots of events both native and custom then using `trigger` is very common

Comment: @charlietfl No it's not. Triggering an event when what you really want is to invoke some explicit behavior is just lazy and misleading.

Comment: @palx .... again, that is very subjective and depends a lot on coding style

Comment: Could somebody answer why I this line of code `$("#trans0_sub").html("<option value="" selected>Select Adviser's Subjects</option>");` can't be detected in my presented codes? I'm just learning the languages from the beginning.

Comment: @Calvin try seeing if `$("#trans0_sub")` exists when you call that.... `console.log($("#trans0_sub").length)`...should be 1. Also make sure you are not repeating ID's in page. They must be unique by definition

Comment: @plalx - dude, you gave me an idea and it works right now! I can manipulate the options now. and charlietfl thanks too. Somehow, Bootstrap's selectpicker is messing around and I need to refresh in time to time.

Comment: @charlietfl Well, whatever I say you could just answer that it's subjective so I guess there is no point arguing. No need for expertise, it's all subjective, there's no right or wrong and everyone is happy ;)

Comment: not trying to beleaguer it, as there are definitely different approaches and styles, but a library like bootstrap for example is extremely event oriented and full of triggers and developer reacts to those events

Comment: @charlietfl When the intention is to **notify** then it's perfectly fine to trigger an event. What I'm saying is that you usually shouldn't trigger an event in order to invoke a specific behavior because you failed to decouple the behavior itself from the handler and therefore have no other choice to trigger an event rather than invoking the behavior directly.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` events works only if the **user** interacts with the element, so, to work, you will have to activate the event by hand, like

```
$('select').html('blabla').change();
```

With this you may be able to achieve what you want :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what I already posted 6 minutes ago ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it does not help answering why I can't do something like $("#trans0_sub").html("<option value="" selected>Select Adviser's Subjects</option>"); in a new added element